# "outer product" of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

What is the "outer product" of modules? Can someone link me a definition and maybe an example? In my book the outer product is noted with $\bigwedge ^tF$, $F$ a $A$-Module, $A$ principle ideal domain. $x_1,...,x_r$ basis of F, the basis of the product is noted as $x_{i_1}\wedge...\wedge x_{i_t}$ wih $1<=i_1<...<i_t<=r$. It also says $x_{i_1}\wedge...\wedge x_{i_t}*(sgn \pi)=x_{\pi(1)}\wedge...\wedge x_{\pi(t)}$ for permutations $\pi$ and if there are indices $i_j=i_l,l\neq j$ then $x_{i_1}\wedge...\wedge x_{i_t}=0$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra

Comment: Note, if you cannot see the connectionection with fields/vector spaces that $F$ can be viewed as a sub-module of a vector space, namely $\text{Frac}(A)\otimes_A\Lambda^t(F)$. The link I gave should be read for the formal details, and the "generalizations" tab indicates that this is legal for general modules over commutative rings.

Comment: Glad to be of service. If you consider your question closed, you can delete it so that there's less clutter and people don't think they still need to address this one. :-)

Comment: How can I delete it?

Comment: I think right at the bottom of the post should be a delete option for the original poster.

Comment: I only see "share edit flag"

Comment: You can probably flag it for a moderator to delete then, you might not have enough reputation to delete posts yet.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that!